# Weird reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I look at yesterday, and I see I've earned 235 points. Only that shouldn't be possible: 200 is fine. Over that, accepted answer gives 15, so 215 and 230 are possible, but not 235.

Then today, I just earned +5 for an answer ([this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36357/characters-that-take-on-a-life-of-their-own/36360#36360), in case it matters). Only, answers are supposed to get +10, unless I've hit my 200 rep quota, which I haven't yet. I'm on 180.

What's going on? Is this some glitch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't figure out how you earned 236 reputation yesterday.  You don't have any unusual rep events that day -- just votes and acceptances.

As for *today*, I see in your rep history -35 for a user being removed.  I had this happen recently on another site; apparently that rep is still "held against you", so you've reached your rep cap for today even though you haven't earned 200 rep net.  If you're thinking you've been cheated out of a day toward the Epic badge, though, don't worry -- that badge doesn't penalize you either.  You earned 200+ rep and lost 35 rep from a user being deleted; it still counts as having earned 200.

Bounties that you offer work the same way.  If you earn 200 rep and think "hey, this is a great day to get a free bounty!" and offer a bounty of 50, you don't then get to earn 50 more points -- you've reached your daily limit.

Comment: Oh, that actually explains it. I do appear to have capped at 180: I see an answer of mine got more upvotes since I posted here, and no rep change. 20 rep missing today, 20 rep extra yesterday (215 are accounted for - one accepted answer) - it evens out. So I guess it's just something weird with how the -35 for user being removed gets calculated. And thanks for your note regarding the Epic badge. I was worried. :)

Comment: The 236 might be because of downvotes/un-downvotes. If you undo your downvote on another answer you get one rep that is not in the normal 200 bucket. See [my answer on WorldBuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5276/28789) for more about this weird case. CC: @Galastel

Answer (score 2):

I can't really answer this since I can't check your reputation history, but you check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32161) answer on Meta Stack Exchange about daily reputation caps and exceptions to the rule.

If you accepted any answers or received any bounties, then those didn't count towards your cap. If everything was from votes, well, the system must be bugged in someway.

I suggest checking your reputation log and seeing where everything came from and whether anything was an exception to the cap.

Comment: You can see every users rep log on their [main profile](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/14704/galastel?tab=reputation) (not on their meta profile though). The only thing missing are downvotes.